# how to add hyphen in between string using python

Tags: python

```
import csv

x=[]
y=[]

with open ('x_wind.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
```

I have wrote above code to extract data from a file

now , i want my data should print as 2018-06-14:1

sample data is

2018061402,6.8750
2018061403,8.0000
2018061404,7.7500
2018061405,7.3750
2018061406,6.7500
2018061407,6.1250
2018061408,5.7500
2018061409,5.6250
2018061410,5.5000
2018061411,5.5000
2018061412,5.3750
2018061413,5.1250
2018061414,4.6250
2018061415,3.8750
2018061416,3.5000
2018061417,3.1250
2018061418,3.6250
2018061419,4.2500
2018061420,4.7500
2018061421,5.8750
2018061422,6.2500
2018061423,6.6250
2018061500,6.7500
2018061501,6.7500
2018061502,7.3750
2018061503,7.1250
2018061504,6.1250
2018061505,5.2500
2018061506,4.7500
2018061507,4.1250
2018061508,4.0000
2018061509,3.8750
2018061510,3.8750
2018061511,4.1250
2018061512,4.5000
2018061513,4.3750
2018061514,3.5000
2018061515,3.1250
2018061516,3.1250
2018061517,3.0000
2018061518,3.0000
2018061519,3.5000
2018061520,3.8750
2018061521,4.1250
2018061522,4.3750
2018061523,4.6250
2018061600,5.1250
2018061601,4.8750
2018061602,6.0000
2018061603,5.5000
2018061604,4.7500
2018061605,3.8750
2018061606,3.3750
2018061607,2.7500
2018061608,2.3750
2018061609,2.5000
2018061610,2.7500
2018061611,3.1250
2018061612,3.3750
2018061613,3.6250
2018061614,3.2500
2018061615,2.7500
2018061616,3.1250
2018061617,2.8750
2018061618,1.5000
2018061619,1.5000
2018061620,1.6250
2018061621,1.8750
2018061622,2.6250
2018061623,3.3750
2018061700,4.1250
2018061701,4.7500
2018061702,6.1250
2018061703,6.1250
2018061704,5.5000
2018061705,5.0000
2018061706,4.2500
2018061707,4.0000
2018061708,3.8750
2018061709,4.0000
2018061710,4.3750
2018061711,4.5000
2018061712,4.5000
2018061713,4.0000
2018061714,3.5000
2018061715,3.0000
2018061716,2.7500
2018061717,2.2500
2018061718,0.3750
2018061719,1.5000
2018061720,2.1250
2018061721,2.1250
2018061722,2.2500
2018061723,3.1250
2018061800,4.2500
2018061801,5.5000
2018061802,7.1250
2018061803,7.1250
2018061804,6.3750
2018061805,5.7500
2018061806,5.3750
2018061807,5.0000
2018061808,5.1250
2018061809,5.0000
2018061810,5.0000
2018061811,4.7500
2018061812,4.6250
2018061813,4.5000
2018061814,4.2500
2018061815,3.7500
2018061816,3.3750
2018061817,3.2500
2018061818,3.1250
2018061819,3.0000
2018061820,3.1250
2018061821,3.2500
2018061822,3.3750
2018061823,3.3750
2018061900,3.5000
2018061901,3.3750
2018061902,4.3750
2018061903,5.8750
2018061904,5.8750
2018061905,5.3750
2018061906,4.7500
2018061907,3.6250
2018061908,3.5000
2018061909,2.6250
2018061910,3.0000
2018061911,2.5000
2018061912,2.0000
2018061913,1.3750
2018061914,0.5000
2018061915,-0.2500
2018061916,-0.5000
2018061917,0.6250
2018061918,2.2500
2018061919,2.0000
2018061920,2.1250
2018061921,2.1250
2018061922,2.7500
2018061923,3.1250
2018062000,3.1250
2018062001,3.0000
2018062002,3.5000
2018062003,5.0000
2018062004,5.1250
2018062005,4.5000
2018062006,3.7500
2018062007,3.2500
2018062008,3.3750
2018062009,2.8750
2018062010,2.7500
2018062011,2.5000
2018062012,1.8750
2018062013,1.2500
2018062014,0.3750
2018062015,0.1250
2018062016,0.5000

## 2018062017,1.8750

Comment: Please see how to create a [mcve].  A couple of rows of your file would suffice

Comment: Your data set is not very clear. Can you please format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a list of datetime object.
You can use the datetime module to convert it to your required format.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
data = "2018061402"
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(data[:-2], "%Y%m%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d") )
```

**Output:**

```
2018-06-14
```

Comment: Actually it's a data of date and time but I just want to separate each string with an hyphen